# Time trigger to cut & paste row when cell equals N/A

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with the following 2 sheets:

Sheet1 "Induction Checklist" is a list of current staff (around 400) from A3:M - Row 2 is the header row.

Sheet2 "Induction Checklist - Staff Left" is a duplicate of Sheet1 but a list of previous staff from A3:M - Row 2 has the same headers as Sheet1

Column C is the Staff ID (number) in both sheets.

Column C of Sheet1 has an ImportRange/Vlookup formula to an entirely different spreadsheet (Source Sheet) to find the Staff ID. When the employee is removed from the Source Sheet, the formula can't find the employee so the value in column C of Sheet1 changes to "N/A".

I want to create a time-based trigger to find the "N/A" values in column C of Sheet1, then cut and paste only those rows to Sheet2 and delete the same rows from Sheet1. If "N/A" is not found, do nothing.

This is a sample of my spreadsheet:

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oXWxg9_YYzZt6bli1RwC6S0TnlYvR-mYvgqD94r2zLY/edit?usp=sharing)

I have the following script but can't get it to work. I would really appreciate some help.

```js
function removeOldStaff() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Induction Checklist");
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var column = 3
  var errorColumn = range.getColumn();
  var errorRow = range.getRow();
  var error = range.getValue();
  var value = "N/A"
  if(error == value && errorColumn == column && errorRow > 3 && sheet.getName() == sheetName) {
    var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var row = sheet.getRange(errorRow, 1, 1, numCols).getValues();
    var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Induction Checklist - Staff Left");
    // Get first empty row:
    var emptyRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    // Copy values from 'Induction Checklist'
    destinationSheet.getRange(emptyRow, 1, 1, numCols).setValues(row);
    sheet.deleteRow(errorRow);
    
  }
   }
```

Comment: Try to read the document and start with something simple. You should `range.getValues()` and iterate it. Besides, you only need `var range = sheet.getRange(3, column, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, 1);`, and the checks of row and column could be eliminated.

Comment: Been working on this all day and still struggling to find a solution

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information? Also, is "making this a time trigger" part of your question?

Comment: I have added a sample of my spreadsheet. I don't need help with the time trigger. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are not iterating through the different rows in your range. For example, `range.getValue()` will only return the value of the top-left cell in the range, in your case `A1`. That's hardly what you want to look for. Similarly, functions like `getColumn()` or `getRow()` don't make sense in this context.

#### Solution:

- Use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to get all the values in your range in a 2D array, and iterate through that (for example, with [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)).
- For each row, check the value in column `C`.
- If the value is `#N/A`, push the full row of data to and array with all the rows to copy (`dataToCopy` in the sample below), and delete the row from the source sheet (you should loop in reverse order because otherwise deleting the rows would mess with the row indexes).
- Copy `dataToCopy` to the target sheet via [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

#### Code sample:

```
function removeOldStaff() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Induction Checklist");
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Induction Checklist - Staff Left");
  var firstRow = 3;
  var column = 3;
  var value = "#N/A";
  var values = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dataToCopy = [];
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var row = values[i];
    var errorValue = row[column - 1];
    if (errorValue == value) {
      dataToCopy.push(row);
      sheet.deleteRow(firstRow + i);
    }
  }
  // Get first empty row:
  var emptyRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  // Copy values from 'Induction Checklist'
  destinationSheet.getRange(emptyRow, 1, dataToCopy.length, dataToCopy[0].length).setValues(dataToCopy);
}
```